# Does an instance of android.app.Application always exist?

Tags: android

The documentation says

> The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created.

Are there any exceptions to this? For instance when app is started by means other than launcher (broadcast listener...) can it happen that instance of Application class is not created?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there are two exceptions, but those are very rare edge cases:

- Starting in Android N there's the DirectBoot system, which might boot before the application.
- `ContentProviders.onCreate` method is called before the `Application.onCreate`.

But unless creating an alarm clock or sharing data to another application, developers shouldn't worry about it.